# Assign Static ip to ubuntu

Tags: windows-server-2008, ubuntu

I have installed ubuntu server edition in virtual box. I have already assigned static ip to my host operating system which is Windows Server. I have another ip which I want to assign my guest Ubuntu Server. I known how to assign following things in ubuntu but I don't know how can I find these things from windows. I have another extra ip than host operating system which belongs to the same network. How can I find following things in Windows.

```
iface eth0
inet static
address 192.168.1.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.254
```

This is an example configurations copied from internet. I just only know the static ip address. Please advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only things that you really need are as follows:

> iface eth0
>   inet static
>   address 192.168.1.x
>   netmask 255.255.255.0
>   gateway 192.168.1.x

You can find these with an "ipconfig /all" on your windows server.

Comment: Thanks for your response. i've tried to set it up. but its sending me an error "Destination Host Unreachable"

Comment: When you set up the virtual network interface in VirtualBox, did you set it up as bridged or NAT? It sounds like you probably want it set to bridged.